# Loop to search for missing files in a directory based off of two criteria within a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need a loop to search for missing files in a directory based off of two criteria within a spreadsheet. The criteria are in column A (fundName) and column D (fundDate).

The count of the fund names are dynamic and may sometimes be 50 or 500.
The count of the fund dates are the same, but they will change every quarter.

The spreadsheet looks like this for user input.
[image]

I think I need to create an offset For loop for the fund & date combination.

```vb
Sub Validatename()
    
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim fundName As Variant
    Dim fundDate As Variant
    
    fundName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fund List").Range("A2")
    fundDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fund List").Range("D2")
    
    fileName = Dir("\\ykt1cnfsprd4\xOldfiles\" & "*MonthlyAccountSummary*" & "*" & fundName & "*" & fundDate & "*" & "*" & "*.xlsx*")
    
    While fileName = ""
    
        answer = MsgBox(fundName & fundDate & "monthly Account Summary is missing, would you like to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    
        If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
        fileName = Dir
    
    Wend
```

Comment: the slashes are for the path of the file and then to find the file, there's wildcards. Ive tested this part and it works. My main challenge is to offset fundName and fundDate to point to a different cell in its search.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at Looping the references?

Comment: FaneDuru was talking about the slashes in the date, not the backslashes in the path. Slashes are not valid in filenames on Windows

Comment: I am referencing the date in column D without the slashes. There are no slashes in the file name.

Comment: Ups... only now I observed that A and D were referenced. I thought that it uses C and D...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Missing Files in List (Column)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Validatename()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fund List")
    
    Dim nlCell As Range: Set nlCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    Dim nrg As Range: Set nrg = ws.Range("A2", nlCell)
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim FundName As String
    Dim FundDate As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim Answer As Integer
    
    For Each cCell In nrg.Cells
        FundName = CStr(cCell.Value)
        FundDate = CStr(cCell.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value)
        fName = Dir("\\ykt1cnfsprd4\xOldfiles\" & "*" & "MonthlyAccountSummary" _
            & "*" & FundName & "*" & FundDate & "*" & ".xls" & "*")
        If Len(fName) = 0 Then
            Answer = MsgBox(FundName & " " & FundDate & " " _
                & "monthly Account Summary is missing. " _
                & "Would you like to continue?", _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Missing File") 
            If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        'Else
            'Debug.Print "Found '" & fName & "'."
        End If
    Next cCell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works, but the only challenge is that there are only 3 dates. Basically I want the Macro to go through the entire fund list for each date and then move to the next and stop once there are no more dates. As a workaround I can hard code in the 3 dates.